# Error Correction Model (ECM) procedure

Tags: time-series, cointegration, unit-root, ecm

I am getting familiar with ECM so I would like to ask for help in order to understand it. My goal is: performing a ECM in a multivariate context.

I was reading ECM is part of a Cointegration analisis. This Cointegration follows two main steps:

1. Estimate a long term equilibrium (using levels or log_price), then
2. Perform ECM (using returns).

I also read that before performing the first step I need to verify if the variables (using levels) are following a *unit root process*. In case they don´t, their difference needs to be verified.

My questions are:

- Am I missing something in the procedure?
- let´s suppose I find all varibles are integrated order two `I(2)` expect one which is `I(1)`. Should I use it for the long term equilibrium (step 1)? How to use this information (`I(2)`) in the Cointegration procedure (maybe it needs to be excluded)?
- Can I use some variables for step one, and add some others for the ECM? If yes, what should I need to consider (e.g. do I need to perform more unit root test over those new variables?)

Thx a lot.

Comment: Are you estimating ECM in a bivariate context or do you have more than two variables?

Comment: @dlnB multivariate

Comment: For cointegration, all variables must be $I(1)$.